# Convert into SQL a Magento Model based script

Tags: php, sql, magento

Is there any way to convert a script that use magento model and collection in a script that use direct SQL.

I know it is possible as quite everything :), The question is about an easy and intuitive way that let me get the query from my script and then reuse in a direct DB script.

Why ? I hope to have a faster script.

Code example ?

Suppose this script:

```
function getProd() {

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addTierPriceData();

return $collection;
}
function getTier($prod) {

$t_1 = false;

$_tierPrices = $prod->getTierPrice();

if ($_tierPrices) {

    $_firstTier = array_slice($_tierPrices, 0, 1);

    if (isset($_firstTier[0]))
        $t_1 = $_firstTier[0]['price'];
}

return $t_1;
}

function exec() {

$collection = getProd();

$i = 0;

foreach ($collection as $prod) {

    $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? '' : 'class="odd"';
    $t1 = 0;
    if ($t1 = getTier($prod)) {

            $prod = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());

            $prod->setPrice($t1);
            $prod->save();
            if ($safe)
                set_time_limit(60);
        }
    }
}

exec();
```

**Basically I would like to process all products that has a tier price and substitute the main price of the product with the tier price.**

The script takes more than 9hr on a 12000 products so I guess an SQL approach would be faster but require me to study DB structure.

So If any one has a good approach to convert this in a PHP/SQL script would be great ( something more that only print the collection query )

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a simple one off solution to view what the query is you should be able to do something like `echo $collection->getSelect();`. The `getSelect` function on a collection will return a `Zend_Select` object. This class has a `__toString` function which returns the sql for the currently built query.

Comment: Sorry I just finish to update the question. 
Answer a bit more structured than just a $collection->getSelect(); are wellcome ... What about the update query, for example ?